# Show the console output from R to be shown in an html page in an web application

Tags: html, r

I want to push user data back to R from a html page and then revert all the script output to another html page. I am also executing few shell scripts from the server so I am using cgi for the same. Is there a best practice for executing R and redirect figures and R-console output to html page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you may consider `knitr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you the package shiny.
Its very good for returning plots and tables, but not so much for R-concole output.
You can have a look here:
http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#hello-shiny